# How to calculate savings from given value with function?

Tags: javascript

Should I calculate a savings of 15 % given an amount x?

```js
function main(){
  var salaryAmount = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

  // Complete the function call
  getSaving();
}

// Complete the function
function getSaving(){

};
```

Comment: The fact that you’re a beginner or how long you’ve stuck with this problem doesn’t help clarify what your actual question is — it only distracts from it. So, what is the purpose of your `main` function and your `getSaving` function, and what specifically do you need help with, within the task of completing the functions? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) offers a [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript) and [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are trying to create a function which tells you how much you would need to save in order to be saving 15% of any given salary.

```
function main(){
    var salaryAmount = parseInt(readLine(),10);
    var saving = getSaving(salaryAmount); // we pass the salary to the function
}

function getSaving(salary){ // we add a parameter for the salary
    return salary * 0.15; // we multiply the salary by 15% and return that value
};
```

we could then simplify this code and remove the second function altogether.

```
function main(){
    var salaryAmount = parseInt(readLine(),10);
    var saving = salaryAmount * 0.15; // we calculate the savings here
}
```

Hope this is the answer you were looking for!